# How can we change url of extension installed?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I installed a extension and it automatically  installed on a path  myweb/store   now I want to change that "store" in url to to my "mystore"  is there a specific way to change or diff for every extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in `/app/code/{vendor}/{module}/etc/frontend/routes.xml`.

You should see something like this:

```
<router id="standard">
    <route id="shop" frontName="shop">
        <module name="Vendor_Module" />
    </route>
</router>
```

Just change the `frontName` attribute to `myshop`.